# Omniauth and jwt_authenticatable rails 7 api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rails-api, ruby-on-rails-7

I am trying to add to the Rails API the ability to handle social signins through the mobile application, and while adding omniauth, I am having an issue with my JWT and devise that has already been setup and working. This is triggering the following error:

```
unexpected ',', expecting => (SyntaxError)
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google...
```

This error occurs only when both methods are present, but both independently work fine.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this error I split the devise method into two, adding the omniauthable and omniauth_providers into another call.

---

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
     :jwt_authenticatable, jwt_revocation_strategy: self

devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2]
```